# Spring MongoDB return the special entity's field

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

if I have an entity "Email" ,it has two fields:id,address,subject,date.
if I have an interface implements MongoRepository:

```
public interface EMailRepository extends MongoRepository<EMail, String>
{
    public Page<EMail> findByAddressLike(String address,Pageable pageable);
}
```

I want to find the Email just has id and address values , how to do it?
if I do it just like it :

```
@Query(field="{'id','address'}")
public Page<Email> findByAddressLike(String address,Pageable pageable);
```

it will work?
if not ,could you tell me how to config it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this section of the docs:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html#mongodb.repositories.queries.json-based

In particular, this example:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String>

    @Query(value="{ 'firstname' : ?0 }", fields="{ 'firstname' : 1, 'lastname' : 1}")
    List<Person> findByThePersonsFirstname(String firstname);

}
```

It's quite likely that you simply need to change `field="{'id', 'address'}"` to `fields="{'address': 1}"`, I've left out id since it is always included unless explicitly repressed (i.e. `{_id: 0}`).